# Iterating through an array or getting characters from an open file - are there any advantages of one over the other?

Tags: c++

I'm just wondering if say...

```
ifstream fin(xxx)
```

then

```
char c;
fin.get(c)
```

is any better than putting the entire text into an array and iterating through the array instead of getting characters from the loaded file.

I guess there's the extra step to put the input file into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is 237 GB, then iterating over it is more feasible than copying it to a memory array.

If you iterate, you still want to do the actual disk I/O in page sized chunks (not go to the device for every byte). But streams usually provide that kind of buffering.

So what you want is a mix of both.